# Confidence intervals with Bootstrap-t vs. Bootstrap-t Variance Stabilized: which works better?

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

In *Efron & Tibshirani 1993. Introduction to the Bootstrap. Chapman-Hall/CRC, Chapter 12*, the authors discuss Bootstrap-t confidence intervals. They state that "bootstrap-t confidence intervals work better for variance stabilized parameters", and describe an algorithm to implement this notion.

They ask, in exercise 12.5, a study comparing the performance of several methods for confidence intervals, including the theoretical, standard, bootstrap-t and bootstrap-t variance stabilized (both non-parametric)

[image]

The exercise is almost identical to Example 3 in *Tibshirani 1988. Variance Stabilization and the Bootstrap. Biometrika 75(3)*.

To solve the exercise, I used a simulation study: 10000 MC and 1000 bootstrap steps in each MC simulation step.  The study showed that for a 90% confidence interval, the approximate uncoverage rate (two-sided, close to 10% would be ideal) for each method is

Standard: $16\%\ \ \ $  [frequency of MC simulations with $\theta=1$ out of the 90% c.i.]

BC$_a$: $15\%$

Bootstrap-t: $11\%$

Bootstrap-t variance stabilized: $15\%$

These results agree closely to those presented in Tibshirani 1988, Example 3 using 1000 MC simulations.

That is, Bootstrap-t variance stabilized is outperformed by plain Bootstrap-t, in this simple situation related to inference for the variance from Normal samples.

Tibshirani 1988 (above) argues, based on similar findings in his Example 3, that "*it is suprising that bootstrap-t performs better than the BC$_a$ and variance stabilized bootstrap procedures. We do not have a good explanation for this*".

**My questions:**

1. Is there a good explanation for this finding?
2. In which situations will variance stabilized bootstrap-t tend to clearly outperform plain bootstrap-t? can you provide an illustrative example in which this happens.